# Select Columns runtime in LINQ LIST<>

Tags: c#, linq

I have `List<Employee> listEmployees`

I want to select some dynamic columns which are not known at compile time, like:

```
 var result = from l listEmployees
              select ""
```

I tried `listEmployees.select("Name");`

But it throws an error saying:

> 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

How can I select only the columns which are determined at runtime?

Comment: @SLaks For performance sakes, like if I need just a few columns out of 300 columns in the table, is it not better to select just the columns I need? Or are you saying that it is still good enough (performance wise) to select the entire row, and use the columns needed?

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ: You should specify the columns you need at compile time.  If you don't know them at compile time, you probably shouldn't be using LINQ.

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).

Comment: i tried it.. but still doesn't work.. I have datasource in LIST<> so it doesn't work

Comment: @ghanshyam.mirani: Call `.AsQueryable()`.

Comment: Hi.. tried listEmployees.AsQueryable().Select("Name"); still it doesn work

Comment: Is there any way to do it natively, I mean without using any third-party libraries?

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ: You can build an expression tree using Reflection.

Comment: @SLaks Can you please give a link or something where I can learn how to do that from?

Answer (score 1):

You could use dynamic linq, it is a open source project which I have used for really dynamic linq queries:

[Article on Scott's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Hope that helps.

Comment: How to do it when we have LIST<Employee> because Employee is class not a databaseTable context

Comment: @ghanshyam.mirani Sorry, I don't understand your question, DynamicLinq doesn't just work on data tables, it will work on POCO's.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a really horrible approach that works

```
var result = from l in listEmployees
             select l.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(l, null);
```

Where propertyName is whatever string you pass at runtime.

Of course, you probably want to extract the bit after the select as a method and add some checking.

Comment: He doesn't know at compile-time what he will want to include.